# The URI that MessageWebSocket uses to connect can be an IP address, correct?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-8, websocket

I see this line at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh994397(v=win.10).aspx:

```
Uri server = new Uri(ServerAddressField.Text.Trim());
...
await webSocket.ConnectAsync(server);
```

I'm hoping that the string passed to URI's constructor can be an IP address; is this so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Uri` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) should accept any valid uniform resource identifier passed to it.

So for instance if your endpoint does not have a DNS record and you need to specify by IP address then using the IP address in place of the domain name should be fine.

```
//By Name
var namedUri = Uri("http://websocketserver/myendpoint");
//By IP address
var addressUri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/myendpoint");
```